# Where to get a notarized document certified in Nashville, TN?

Tags: united-states, tennessee

I've spent half my day browsing government websites and calling various departments and I'm at a loss.

I'm trying to get a Single Status Affidavit notarized and then get it authenticated with an Apostille to use it abroad.

Could anyone explain to me where I should take my notarized document, to get the notary signature certified as stated in [this step-by-step process](https://sos.tn.gov/businesses/guides/apostille-authentication-guide). I've found a Notary Public that is willing to notarize it but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: There are two different procedures, depending on whether the country you are sending it to is a member of the [Apostille Convention](https://www.hcch.net/en/instruments/conventions/specialised-sections/apostille). So what country is it going to? The answer by user71659 is the right way to start, no matter which country.

Comment: @GerardAshton That part I luckily already know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the seal the notary affixes to your document and see what county it says, or ask the notary when they do it. Look up the clerk of that county and take the notarized document to their office and ask them to certify the signature for an Apostille.

For example, the city of Nashville is in Davidson County. If the notary has their commission in Davidson County, you'd go to the [Davidson County Clerk](https://www.nashville.gov/departments/county-clerk).

Comment: Thanks! What service am I looking for? I don't see 'certify notary signature' or anything similar on the services page here. I called them and the lady said: "We don't do that here, you need to be at the department of Health and Vital Records.". They don't list such services either. So now I'm wondering whether the lady on the phone misheard me or something.

Comment: @Jochem They probably heard the word "certified" and thought you were looking for a birth certificate. I'd go down to them with the document and a printout of the page you linked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as the OP. I spent quite a bit of time looking carefully through the Davidson County Clerk website to determine where to get a notary signature certified, so that I can get an apostille for a document. The apostille application form from the TN Secretary of State specifies that public documents have to be notarized and certified prior to getting the apostille. This morning I called this number at the Davidson County Clerk: (615) 862-6256. This is the number for the Notary Department where people can submit applications to become notaries public. The gentleman who answered the phone told me that his department will also certify notary signatures from Davidson County. He said you have to come in person with the document to Howard Office Building, 700 President Ronald Reagan Way in Nashville. The website really should give explicit directions about this process. They have explication instructions for just about everything else.